# Como retornar uma lista como JSON usando Spring MVC (@RestController)?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Quero retornar uma lista no formato JSON usando Spring, porém não estou tendo sucesso. No `pom.xml` eu adicionei esta dependência:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

E meu *controller* está assim:

```
@RestController
public class CandidatosWS {

    @Autowired
    CandidatoService candidatoService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/candidatos/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Candidato>> allCandidatos() {
        List<Candidato> listCandidatos = null;

        try {
            listCandidatos = candidatoService.listarCandidatos();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<List<Candidato>>(listCandidatos, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Porém ao chamar a url pelo Postman, recebo o erro:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>Not Acceptable</body>
</html>
```

Tem mais algum detalhe que não o fiz?

Answer (score 4):

Seu contralador não está com problema, aparentemente o problema está na dependência do Jackson, que é o conversor padrão para JSON registrado pelo Spring. Por padrão o Spring MVC registra estes conversores:

- [`org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.html);
- [`org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/StringHttpMessageConverter.html);
- [`org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ResourceHttpMessageConverter.html);
- [`org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/SourceHttpMessageConverter.html);
- [`org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/support/AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.html);
- [`org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.html);
- [`org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html);

Como o conversor padrão do Jackson precisa de uma versão `2.*`, você deve atualizar para uma versão mais recente do jackson, da qual o conversor padrão registrado faz uso. Para isto, altere a declaração da dependência `jackson-mapper-asl` no seu `pom.xml` por uma da versão `2`, algo assim:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Perceba que tanto o `groupId` quanto o `artifactId` são diferentes da versão que está usando.

Existem outras formas de fazer isto, porém mais trabalhosas, caso seja mandatório usar uma versão antiga do Jackson no seu projeto. Uma é configurar um *view resolver* que resolva pelo conteúdo (`ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`) e uma outra é registrar um conversor que utilizando o *mapper* do Jackson na versão `1.*`. Não sei como está toda sua aplicação, talvez não seja esta a melhor alternativa, mas se for este seu caso, me avise que atualizo a resposta com configuração para estes cenários.

## Considerações sobre serialização no Spring MVC

Sugerido este cenário de acordo com o que disse em sua pergunta, alguns outros pontos podem ser verificados em sua aplicação em busca da solução do teu problema.

Algo a se observar é que não é obrigatório informar explicitamente no `@RequestMapping` que o *end-point* irá produzir JSON, ou XML, ou HTML, como é sugerido na outra resposta, isto de certa forma limita a flexibilidade que o Spring MVC lhe proporciona, como em casos que você precise alterar o tipo de mídia retornada. Revisar todos os mapeamentos não é um serviços muito legal...

A boa prática é configurar diversos [*messages converters*](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-message-conversion) e deixar a mando do cliente escolher que tipo de mídia ele quer, ou seja, é o cliente que irá dizer qual o tipo de retorno ele quer através de um cabeçalho. Se for algum que nossa aplicação não retorne, daí então é que retornaremos um erro ou ainda podemos considerar um por padrão.

Como dito acima o Spring já configura diversos conversores, então o que precisamos fazer é apenas garantir o tipos de mídia que nossa aplicação irá tratar, assim também como configurar uma padrão. Em XML podemos fazer desta forma:

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />

<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <value>
            json=application/json
            xml=application/xml
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

E o equivalente em Java é isto:

```java
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(final ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.parameterName("mediaType")
            .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}
```

Tanto em XML quanto em Java fizemos a mesma coisa, falamos que o tipo de conteúdo padrão será JSON (`defaultContentType`) e limitamos os tipos de mídia com os quais nossa aplicação irá trabalhar (`mediaTypes`).

Depois de feito isto, podemos testar. No Postman pode ser feita uma requisição a `http://localhost:8080/<seu_context>/test/candidatos`, com ou sem o cabeçalho `Accept`, mas podemos usar também algo como `curl`. Isto:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/<seu_context>/test/candidatos
```

Ou isto:

```
curl --header "Accept:application/json" http://localhost:8080/<seu_context>/test/candidatos
```

Irá retornar isto no meu exemplo:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Pedro da Silva"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Paula Pereira"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nome": "<anonimo>"
  }
]
```

Se informarmos como valor `application/xml` para o cabeçalho `Accept`, teremos este retono:

```xml
<List xmlns="">
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <nome>Pedro da Silva</nome>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <nome>Paula Pereira</nome>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <nome>&lt;anonimo&gt;</nome>
    </item>
</List>
```

Usando `curl`, seria algo assim:

```
curl --header "Accept:application/xml" http://localhost:8080/<seu_context>/test/candidatos
```

Obs.: no retorno em XML o nome das propriedade, *namespace*, etc., podem ser alterados por você.

Por fim, algumas observações, outras boas práticas:

- não é necessário retornar uma [ResponseEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html), ela é normalmente usada quando informamos um *status* HTTP diferente do que o *container* retornaria, quando estamos usando `RestTemplate` ou quando não informamos explicitamente [`@ResponseBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html). Neste último caso, `@ResponseBody` já vem herdada quando usamos `@RestController`;
- não é necessário converter nada para um `JSONObject`, como sugere também a outra resposta, isso é trabalho e desnecessário. Quando falamos através da `@ResponseBody` que o retorno será serializado, que será o *payload* da resposta, o Spring irá escolher o conversor mais apropriado de acordo com o cabeçalho informado pelo cliente (cabeçalho HTTP `Accept`) ou o configurado como padrão. Dito isto, você pode simplemente retornar uma lista de candidatos (`List<Candidato>`);

Então, considerando também estas observações, seu `CandidatosWS` poderia se parecer com isto:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class CandidatosWS {

    @Autowired
    private CandidatoService candidatoService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/candidatos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Candidato> allCandidatos() {
        return candidatoService.listarCandidatos();
    }

}
```

Um exemplo completo funcionando pode ser visto neste [gist](https://gist.github.com/brunocesarsilva/1e8a05af72c8f8455293), caso você queira ver como pode ficar mais simples o seus controladores, deixando a cargo do Spring a serialização.

Answer (score 0):

Altere de:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/candidatos/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Para

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/candidatos/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Depois, você precisa retornar uma lista de JSONObject:

```
List<JSONObject> listCandidatos = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
```

E para populá-lo, você precisa converter o `Candidato` para um `JSONObject`. Existem maneiras diferentes de fazer isto:

- usar uma biblioteca como [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) ou o próprio [Jackon](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) para isto.
- converter manualmente, criando uma instância de JSONObject e preenchendo campo a campo

E para retornar:

```
return new ResponseEntity<List<JSONObject>>(listCandidatos, HttpStatus.OK);
```

## Código final

O código ficaria assim, então:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/candidatos/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<Candidato>> allCandidatos() {

    List<Candidato> listCandidatos = /* busca de candidatos*/

    List<JSONObject> listCandidatosJson = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (Candidato cand : listCandidatos ) {
        JSONObject candidatoJson = cand.toJson(); //implemente o método toJson(), conforme sugerido
        listCandidatosJson.add(candidatoJson);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<List<JSONObject>>(listCandidatosJson, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Não é preciso converter nada para `JSONObject`, spring já tem conversores para isso, só configurar. Já imaginou ter que implementar `toJson();` em todas as entidades, ou ainda chamar explicitamente no controlador para ser serializado? É muito trabalho que o spring já faz pra gente ;)

Comment: @BrunoCésar, agradeço as observações. Foi só um exemplo o código acima, ele não precisaria implementar em todas as entidades, depende da necessidade dele. Não sabia que o Spring tinha conversores, sempre vi código usando Jackson e GSon convertendo explicitamente os objetos para JSON. De todo modo, não vejo motivos para negativarem uma resposta que, pelo menos até onde sei, não está incorreta.

Comment: @Dherik Acho que o único problema com a resposta é a palavra *precisa*. O usuário não precisa montar o JSON manualmente. Por outro lado, é uma excelente alternativa, já que nem sempre um objeto nos dá o mapeamento desejado ou mesmo queremos criar uma classe para representar um valor simples. Além do que o desempenho de montar um JSON manualmente é muito superior ao que usa reflexão. Então é sempre bom ter em mente uma alternativa.