# Problema com rest controller no Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Configurei o Spring 4 para trabalhar sem xml.

Criei um `@RestController` simples, como este:

```
@RestController
public class JogadorRest {

    @RequestMapping("/ola/{jogador}")
    public Jogador message(@PathVariable String jogador) {

        Jogador j = new Jogador();
        j.setNome(jogador);

        return j;
    }

}
```

Porém ao testar no Postman (http://localhost:8080/RestTestJogador/ola/Lior), recebo um HTML ao invés do json:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>/RestTestJogador/WEB-INF/view/ola/Liorr.jsp</body>
</html>
```

**Porque isso acontece?**

Será a maneira de como configurei o spring? Minha configuração está assim:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("br.com.testejogador.default")
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

Comment: Veja se esta reposta lhe ajuda: [Como retornar uma lista como JSON usando Spring MVC (@RestController)?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82997/como-retornar-uma-lista-como-json-usando-spring-mvc-restcontroller/83407#83407). É de uma outra pergunta sua.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa dizer, no RequestMapping, que seu método quer retornar por exemplo um JSON ou um XML. Como você não definiu nada, ele está usando a convenção de procurar uma JSP baseado no endereço que você digitou.

Alberto